# Could use help in ActionListener and ActionEvent

Tags: swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener, java-7

I am trying to write a program for my `Computer Science` class that disables a `JButton` after it's clicked on `8 times`. However, it disables right after I click on it once. I'm still not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JFrameDisableButton extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrameDisableButton window = new JFrameDisableButton();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    final int WIDTH = 150;
    final int HEIGHT = 150;
    private Font bigFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
    private JButton disableButton = new JButton("Disable");
    private Container pane = getContentPane();
    private JLabel annoyed;

    public JFrameDisableButton()
    {
        super("Disable Frame");
        setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        pane.add(disableButton);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DisableButtonListener disableListener = new DisableButtonListener();
        disableButton.addActionListener(disableListener);
    }

    private class DisableButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
        {
            if(actionPerformed(ActionEvent (click = 8)))
            {
                disableButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                disableButton.setEnabled(true);
                annoyed = new JLabel("That's enough!");
                pane.add(annoyed);
                annoyed.setFont(bigFont);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How you planning to bring the `JButton` in question, back to the `ENABLED` state ? Since once disabled, how to perform an `Action` so that it goes to the `else` part of the `if/else block`.

Comment: Oh. Wait. You're right. But then how would I get it to 8 instances of the JButton being clicked on before disabling?

Comment: Here I had modified your code a bit, have a look at that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here I had modified your code a bit, please have a look, it disables the `JButton`. Though how to bring it back to `Enabled` state, for that, you need to either use another `JButton`, or some sort of another event to bring it back to enabled state. Simply use a `private int counter = 0` variable, that will count the button counts till 8 and then disable the `JButton`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JFrameDisableButton extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /*
         * Do learn about Concurrency in Swing too,
         * to display GUI related updates on the EDT.
         */
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrameDisableButton window = new JFrameDisableButton();
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });        
    }

    final int WIDTH = 150;
    final int HEIGHT = 150;
    private Font bigFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
    private JButton disableButton = new JButton("Disable");
    private Container pane = getContentPane();
    private JLabel annoyed;
    private int counter = 0;

    public JFrameDisableButton()
    {
        super("Disable Frame");

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        pane.add(disableButton);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        DisableButtonListener disableListener = new DisableButtonListener();
        disableButton.addActionListener(disableListener);
        annoyed = new JLabel("Clicked : " + counter + " times.");
        annoyed.setFont(bigFont);
        pane.add(annoyed);
        /*
         * Always call pack()/setSize() methods, only
         * when you are done adding components to 
         * the parent Container. Once it had realized it 
         * components, so that it can calculate, it''s 
         * size in a better way.
         */
        pack();
    }

    private class DisableButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
        {
            counter++;
            if(counter == 8)
            {
                annoyed.setText("Clicked : " + counter + " times.");
                disableButton.setEnabled(false);
                counter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                annoyed.setText("Clicked : " + counter + " times.");                                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what I was doing wrong!
Not sure how I'm supposed to explain to my teacher about how the main method was written though...

Comment: Please have a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). This clearly states what you have explain your teacher about the use of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) or EventQueue.invokeLater(...)` For the rest You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)